# « Like us on Facebook » : aimez-nous, faites-nous (un) j'aime ... ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, informatique, comparaison-de-langues, société

Sur plusieurs sites Web, on a de plus en plus des références aux réseaux sociaux apparaissant au bas de la page d'accueil. Parfois, on nous dit « Suivez-nous/suivez [nom/icône du réseau social] ». Dans d'autres cas on peut retrouver, par exemple, en anglais :

> Like us on Facebook.

Sur son centre de ressources marketing [en français](https://fr.facebookbrand.com/assets/icone-bouton-jaime) ([ailleurs](https://visual.ly/community/infographic/social-media/facebook-translated-around-world)), cette société donne comme exemple « Aimez-nous sur Facebook ­». Est-ce adéquat pour qu'on comprenne ce dont il s'agit, soit essentiellement « Veuillez svp. cliquer sur le bouton “J'aime” de notre page se trouvant sur le site Facebook ». Considère-t-on « Faites-nous un “J'aime” sur Facebook » aussi adéquat, explicite ? Est-ce que le verbe [*aimer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aimer) à l'impératif avec la préposition [*sur*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur) suffisent à former un syntagme cohérent explicitant l'action ou se dont il s'agit en français ? Pourquoi (pas) ; peut-on élaborer par comparaison avec ce qui est usuel en français dans ce genre de contexte ou dans des contextes antérieurs à l'émergence de ces réseaux ?

Comment: Je ferais une distinction entre un lien *Suivez-nous sur FB* qui renverrait *a priori* sur une la page FB, et un lien *Aimez-nous sur FB* qui correspondrait à un *like*.

Comment: En français d'avant les réseaux sociaux, on aurait plutôt dit, à mon avis, faites-nous un bisou, un coucou, un signe d'amitié **sur** quelque chose. Mais le *quelque chose* est très dépendant de la technologie. Tout le monde pense à FB, mais vous pouvez avoir votre propre système d'approbation.

Comment: En tout cas, *faites-nous un j'aime* ou *faites-nous j'aime* relèvent de l'anglicisme face-bookien.

Comment: Incidentally, the question is similar in English; you'd expect some semantic difficulties with using "like" (as it existed pre-Facebook) in the imperative in any language. For a long time you'd see it written, whether spontaneously or by a mini-convention, with quotation marks when the Facebook sense was intended. *Fans are invited to "like" the page on Facebook.* I guess after a decade+, the verb has accommodated the sense "indicate that one likes", because that awkward solution is rare now. Whereas it sounds like *aimer* was spared that semantic loosening en faisant place à *liker*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le verbe ***liker*** (faut-il préciser qu'il s'agit d'un anglicisme...) est très souvent employé :

> ***Likez nous*** sur Facebook.

Il d'abord apparu dans l'édition 2015 du "[Dico des mots qui n'existent pas](http://www.telerama.fr/livres/le-dico-des-mots-qui-nexistent-pas-%28et-quon-utilise-quand-meme%29,119256.php)" mais a fait récemment une entrée officielle dans celui des mots qui existent, [le Robert illustré 2018](http://robert-illustre.lerobert.com/les-mots-nouveaux.php):

> **liker** [lajke] **v. tr.** (de l'anglais *to like* « aimer ») anglic. Indiquer que l'on apprécie (un contenu) sur Internet en cliquant sur le bouton prévu à cet effet. *Liker une photo*.

Je doute fortement que le verbe aimer puisse renverser la vapeur bien que ***un J'aime*** soit une traduction satisfaisante de "**a Like**".

Comment: Il n'ajoute pas à *j'aime*, c'est plutôt le contraire.Sa signification est restreinte à une action spécifique. On peut par exemple dire *je n'aime pas liker* alors que *je n'aime pas aimer* est difficilement intelligible ;-)

Comment: Remarque pertinente. Mais pourtant, les anglophones en sont exactement à ce point: *“I don't like to like”*. Le français s'en sortirait sûrement d'une manière ou d'une autre (par exemple, *«je n'aime pas aimer sur Facebook»* ou même simplement *«je n'aime pas sur Facebook»*). Tout comme les anglophones peuvent broder: *“I don't like Facebook Likes”*.

Comment: Oui, mais comme le néologisme apporte une solution plus simple à ce problème, il durera probablement tant que Facebook existera, comme le verbe *twitter* [twuite] est lié à Twitter [twuitɛʁ] .

Comment: Je ne le nie pas. Vous avez vraisemblablement raison.

Comment: [twuite]????? On dit [twiːte] au Québec, je veux bien admettre [twite] par les Européens (certaines conjugaisons seraient un désagréable doublon de *twit* au Québec, lequel est utilisé pour désigner un idiot), mais vraiment, [twuite] me semble surréaliste!

Comment: [twuite] fait *twou-i-thé*. J'ai de la difficulté à imaginer le son TWOU... *Tout-oui-thé* serait [tuwite].

Comment: @Feelew Je mal retranscript, c'est bien [twite] !

Comment: Concernant le dernier point avec le substantif, pourquoi mettez-vous ok entre parenthèses. Il est facile a traduire dans le sens où si l'on met entre guillemets avec une majuscule c'est bcp plus clair : un « J'aime », non ? Faites « J'aime » chez nous ? Faites « J'aime » pour nous ? Il prend le déterminant pour rendre ça plus clair. Pourquoi ça marcherait pour _clin d’œil_ et pas pour ça. C'est que « j'aime » est une périphrase avec de multiples ellipses, et ça « déborde » ou c'est mal ficelé ? C'est intéressant. Merci !

Comment: Oui, un *j'aime* ou un *J'aime* traduit très bien un *like*, et en plus est déjà présent dans la question. J'avais commencé par mettre un *aime* qui n'est guère envisageable mais après avoir ajouté "un *j'aime* (ok)", ma dernière remarque ne tient plus.